# Set height of iframe to x% of screensize

Tags: css, iframe, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using boostrap 3, I'm trying to embed a presentation on the page. Its not the only element on the page. There are many other rows above & below this:

```
<div class="row">
<div id="iframecontainter" class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-1">
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/presenation.ppt&embedded=true" frameborder="0"></iframe> 
</div> <!-- #iframecontainter -->
</div> <!-- .row -->
```

& css:

```
iframe{
width:100%
}
```

Above codes are taking care of width as I want. But its the height that is causing the problem. Is there a way I can set height: %of available screen size? or otherwise what is the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
html, body{ height: 100%; }
.row, #iframecontainter{height: 100%; }
iframe{
    height:80%; border: 1px solid red;
}
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ewLzr/)

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript to assign a height of iframe tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function calcHeight()
{
//find the height of the internal page
var the_height=
document.getElementById('the_iframe').contentWindow.
document.body.scrollHeight;
//change the height of the iframe
document.getElementById('the_iframe').height= the_height;
}
</script>
<iframe width="100%" src="./1BA3A.mht" scrolling="no" id="the_iframe" onLoad="calcHeight();" height="1px" frameborder="0" ></iframe>
```

Thanks.